# Solr Filter for Logging/Analysing Queries

Tags: lucene, solr

I'm using Solr and wish to be able to log queries/tokens to a database for analytics for both marketing and suggested search functionality.

I'm guessing that a Lucene filter would be a good way of doing this, maybe putting a filter in the query filter chain for a given field type which logs to a specified database. I'm wondering the best way to do this to minimize the impact on Solr response times.

If anybody has done this in the past and is willing to share their solution, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way is to just analyze the access log, and consume that data into a report. This could be done offline, and would have no affect on response times.

Comment: Access log does not provide any if on what's been found. This log is produced in HTTP layer.

Comment: Technically the OP asked to log just the queries, not the results, so using the access log should get you the info you need, but you need to parse it.